# How to join the same table 2 times with different aliases and conditions using Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables:

User table:

```
---------------
userId | name 
---------------
1      | Alice
2      | Bob
3      | Charly
---------------
```

Project table:

```
-------------------------------------
projectId | userId | state  | color
-------------------------------------
4         | 1      | active | red
5         | 1      | closed | blue
6         | 2      | closed | green
7         | 3      | active | yellow
-------------------------------------
```

Topic table:

```
--------------------------------
topicId | projectId | topicName
--------------------------------
7       | 4         | D
8       | 4         | e
9       | 5         | D
10      | 6         | D
--------------------------------
```

Associations:

```
User.hasMany(model.Project)
Project.hasMany(model.Topics)
```

I'd like to find all `User`s who:

- have at least one `project`, which is connected to some `topic` on condition (where `name='D'`);
- include all `projects` that are in `active` state;

So, as a result, I want to have

```
--------------------------------------
userId | userName | projectId | color
--------------------------------------
1      | Alice    | 4         | red
2      | Bob      | 6         | green
--------------------------------------
```

Something like this:

```
const users = await User.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Project,
        include: [{
            model: Topics,
            where: { name: 'D' },
            attributes: [],
        }],
        attributes: [],
    }, {
        model: Project,
        where: { status: 'active'},
        required: false,
        attributes: ['color'],
    }]
})
```

I can solve this issue if I add one more association:

```
User.hasMany(models.Project, { as: 'ProjectTopics' });
```

and add to the query `as: ProjectTopics` on the 4th line.
But I don't want to have two associations to the same table with the same keys, just with different aliases.

There is a line in [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-findAll):

```
options.include[].through.as  
The alias for the join model, in case you want to give it a different name than the default one.
```

Could you help me to understand how it works and how I can use this for my issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is useful if your query includes the same model multiple times, but with different conditions or attributes. In this case, when you join to the project model a second time, you can specify a custom alias for the join table using the through.as option.

```
const users = await User.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Project,
      include: [{
        model: Topics,
        where: { name: 'D' },
        attributes: [],
      }],
      attributes: [],
      through: { as: 'ProjectTopics' }
    },
    {
      model: Project,
      where: { status: 'active'},
      required: false,
      attributes: ['color'],
      through: { as: 'ActiveProjects' }
    }
  ]
})
```

In this example, the first instance of the Project instance is named ProjectTopics, and the second instance is named ActiveProjects. This allows you to include two instances of the project template in a query with different features and characteristics.